# Metrics endpoint isn't available since Spring Boot 2.0.2-RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

Starting with Spring Boot 2.0.2-RELEASE actuator 'metrics' endpoint isn't available even using following configuration:

```
management:
  endpoints.web.exposure.include: "*"
```

The same configuration exposes metrics endpoint with Spring Boot 2.0.0-RELEASE

pom.xml:

```
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ....
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: It seems your configuration has not the right format.Could you try to put above configuration as format yml. I mean management: endpoint : web : exposure : include: * with appropriate spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found that there is an instance of `org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.MetricsEndpoint` should exist in Spring context in order to let Actuator show '/metrics' endpoint.

```
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MetricsEndpointAutoConfiguration
```

is responsible to create an instance of MetricsEndpoint but for some reason it never creates it.

So, I've created this bean in my own configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public MetricsEndpoint metricsEndpoint(MeterRegistry registry) {
        return new MetricsEndpoint(registry);
    }
```

It's fixed the problem but I'm not sure this this the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar sample . My  application.yml is like this.

[image: application.yml]